# User "none" role

Tags: users, user-roles

Can someone explain what does the "none" user role mean in WordPress?

Which capabilities has this user role?

Is it a good practise to use that role for a basic user registration?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? In standard vanilla WordPress there is no role by the name of "none"

Comment: When you create a new user with PHP, you can set the role "none", which will appear in the users page